# How can I convert 3 int values to single int value then restore

Tags: php, int

How can I convert 3 int values to single int value, then, I can restore there 3 int values via the single int value. e.g.

```
$n1 = 8559800019119; 
$n2 = 99901;
$n3 = 911861;
$result = ????????($n1, $n2, $n3);  //how can I convert $n1, $n2, $n3 to $result
```

and, I will restore there 3 int values.

```
????????($result);

$r1 == $n1 == 8559800019119;
$r2 == $n2 == 99901;
$r3 == $n3 == 911861;
```

Please DO NOT use STRING or ARRAY (such as `explode('|', "{$n1}|{$n2}|{$n3}")`), arithmetic operation only.

Answer (score 0):

In general **there is no solution** for your task.

The storage of a single integer is simply not sufficient to hold the information of *multiple* integers.

By the way: your example number 8559800019119 will not fit into 32 bits. So this will work on 64 bit platforms only. On 32 bit the data type is double precision float rather than integer.

---

However, under certain circumstances there might be a work around.

### Case #1 - restricted value domain

If the value domain of the integers is restricted to use only less bits than native php integers then you can pack them by shift operators. E.g.:

```
assert($n1 >= 0 && $n1 <= 255);
assert($n2 >= 0 && $n2 <= 1023);
assert($n3 >= 0 && $n3 <= 16383);

# pack
$packed = $n1 | ($n2<<8) | $n3<<18;

# unpack
$r1 = $packed & 255;
$r2 = ($packed >> 8) & 1023;
$r3 = ($packed >> 18) & 16383;
```

### Case #2 - independent storage

If you have the option to store your values somewhere else using a unique integer (auto-)ID as key - e.g. in a *database* or a *file* with a name containing the key - you might pass the key ID instead of the actual values and read the original values back later using the unique key passed as single integer.

The drawback of solutions like this is that you usually need some kind of cleanup to get rid of old orphaned value tuples. Furthermore you need some logic to create unique IDs.